# My Recurring Task doesn't get called

Tags: android

I am trying to use AlarmManager to accomplish a recurring task. I am using setInexactRepeating() and have set the interval to every 15 minutes (just for testing purposes) however, it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.w("CacheCrusader", "Recurring Job: Clearing Cache");

        }

 }
```

Setter

```
private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {


            Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
            updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

            Intent downloader = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    0, downloader, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(
                    Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, recurringDownload);
        }
```

Code that Sets the Setter

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
     setRecurringAlarm(context);
```

Android Manifest Declaration

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

No errors are generated in the logcat... the alarm just never fires.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's inexact so... If you set it the interval to 15 mins, you have to wait for at least half an hour to be sure it has/has not fired. *After* the starting time you have set (20:15). Try it out with something like 1 min interval for testing. And, if you need a more reliable schedule, use `setRepeating()`, or possibly `set()` where each alarm invocation registers the next one.

Comment: Right.  The inexact thing sets a floor.  Your alarm will happen no more often than 15 minutes.  The upper limit is bigger than that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Unfortunately I have been waiting for over 4 hours and the alarm has still not been triggered.

Comment: Maybe your app is crashing? That would clear the alarms. In any case, using `set()` and registering the next alarm manually is the most reliable way to use alarms. You might want to try it.